# What to add to prevent my <table> content from shrinking with browser size?

Tags: html, css

What should I add to my html/css code so that the content under the  tag does not go out of place when I minimize browser's size?

The content involves pictures on the left side column and text on the right side. the text is the one that goes all over the place when I manipulate the size of the browser.

my code:

```
<table cellspacing="40px;">

 <tr>
    <td> <img src="xx.jpg" width="200" height="290" 
style="border:40px solid white;">
    </td>

    <td>
    text....
    </td>

 </tr>

 <tr>
    <td> <img src="yy.jpg" width="200" height="290" style="border:40px solid white;">
    </td>

    <td>
    text....
    </td>

 </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Please show us your code and what you are trying to do

Comment: Note that `cellspacing="40px;"` is an error; if browsers do use 40 pixels there it's due to error correction, and you can't rely on it working everywhere! Also, it's deprecated and you're better off using the CSS equivalent of `border-spacing`.

Comment: @MrLister Noted, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Not sure if of your code since it isn't posted but have you defined a specific width on that column that is not a percentage? If you want it to stay at 100px wide, for example, explicitly put that on your column as its width.

```
.col-right{
  width: 100px !important;
}
```

Comment: Set it to `<table cellspacing="40px;" style="width:670px !important;">`and it's in the perfect size and fixed position. Thank you!

Comment: I downvoted this answer because it tells the OP to use `!important`.

Comment: @maya You don't have to use !important if you do not have any other styles that will overwrite this width. I only added it as we didn't have the code prior to sending an answer.

Comment: @OsuDani I understand, did a quick search what !important means. Thanks!